# Match text using regex, but do not match if the text is inside certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following text

> testing this $testing this$ testing this

If I use replace function of javascript as `replace(/test/g, "9");`, the following output is generated

> 9ing this $9ing this$ 9ing this

How to specify to exclude any parsing between $$ so that I get the following output

> 9ing this $testing this$ 9ing this

I am able to generate the desired output by using a callback function with the match `/\$[^$]*\$|(test)/` But is there a simple way around? please help

Comment: A pure regex would be find `((?:\$[^$]*\$[^$]*?)*?)test` replace `\19` or `${1}9`

Comment: Seen here https://regex101.com/r/XevoHB/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `((?:\$[^$]*\$[^$]*?)*?)test`
Replace `${1}9`

Tested
https://regex101.com/r/XevoHB/1

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           \$ [^$]* \$ 
           [^$]*? 
      )*?
 )                             # (1 end)
 test
```

JS code

```
const regex = /((?:\$[^$]*\$[^$]*?)*?)test/g;
const str = `testing this \$testing this\$ testing this`;
const subst = `${1}9`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little clumsy, but works. You could explode the string on `$`, then re-assemble it:

```
function toNine(str) {
    return str.replace(/test/g, '9');
}

function transformInput(input) {
    portions = input.split('$');
    return toNine(portions[0]) +
        '$' + portions[1] + '$' +
        toNine(portions[2]);
}

const input = 'testing this $testing this$ testing this';
console.log(transformInput(input));
```

Comment: this is better than using callback function. thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
/[$]test/g      //correspond to all occurrences of "test" with the '$' char before
```

so in 3 lines:

```
var text = "testing this $testing this$ testing this";

text=text.replace(/[$]test/g, "ignore"); 
text=text.replace(/test/g, "9");
text=text.replace(/ignore/g, "$test");
```

---

Solution without the markup error:

```
var text = "testing this $testing this$ testing this ";
var array = text.split(" ");

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    
    if (array[i].contains("$test")){ 
      //do nothing 
    }
    else{
      array[i] = array[i].replace(/test/g, "9");
    }
}

text = array.join(" ");
```

Comment: but this is not a generalized solution. if the markup can happen in any arbitrary manner, this solution cannot be applied.